# reverse engineer IOS Gamekit session messages

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, gamekit, packet-sniffers

I want to write a third party Iphone app that can receive messages from a peer to peer
GameKitSession.

Is it possible to reverse engineer peer to peer messages when you have the sessionId? 
I have tried Wifi sniffing, but cannot see any data transmitted
from the controlling iphone app. I have written an test App the can connect as a client using
the sessionId but only receive events on PeerChanged but nothing on ReceiveData.

Any Ideas on reverseEngineering it?

thanks

Comment: nothing is impossible, but why you want to do it?

Comment: check out mitmproxy: http://mitmproxy.org/

Comment: xlc02012 - so you have an idea then?

Comment: mitmproxy is a http proxy, not sure it would be used by gamekit.

Comment: so noone has an answer on reverse engineering a gamekit session, when you have the sessionId ?